# Replay-based testing method walks into dead end in case of TLS v1.3

Tags: testing, wireshark, tls1.3

It turns out to me that with forward-security and local obfuscation, negotiation in TLS v1.3 does not exchange specific key factors and thus becomes stronger than any of its predecessor in previous versions of TLS protocol.
However, if software testing engineers are asked to conduct on third-party software in black-box in a way of sniffer-to-replay and the communication between its client and server uses TLS v1.3, how should they do it anyway?